# Hyperlink not visible in HTML

Tags: html, hyperlink

Somehow hyperlink on my website isn't showing up correctly.
Here is few images to show you what it looks like at the moment

[Not visible link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3Gut.png)

[The link is there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ie6VL.png)

Here is my code ( most of it isn't mine but I am editing it.

```html
<div class="padding">
  <center>
    <h3>Ota meihin yhteyttä tästä:</h3>
    <a href="http://airduo.fi/tietosuoja.html" target=_ blank> Tietosuojaehdot 
    </a></br>
    <form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
      <table width="450px">
```

Comment: The code is working fine!! Can you explain what your problem is?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve], not a random snippet of your code that doesn't demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<a href="http://airduo.fi/tietosuoja.html" target= _blank style="color:black;"> Tietosuojaehdot 
</a></br>
```